# Scraping Stock Prices from the Web using Python and Xpath for a period of 5 days

Tags: python-3.x, xpath

I have the following code to scrap the stock price of a certain share from the YahooFinance website. I want to scrap this data across 5 days. However, the output gives me the stock price of just the one day at the start, repeated 5 times.

How do I modify the code to give me the output of the share prices for the past 5 days.

The expected output is (this is the actual data of the past 5 days).

```
['1,311.85']    
['1,315.60']    
['1,313.25']  
['1,309.40']  
['1,299.15']
```

**Python Code:**

```
import requests  
from lxml import html  
from datetime import datetime,timedelta  
start_url = "https://in.finance.yahoo.com/quote/HINDUNILVR.NS?p=HINDUNILVR.NS"  
start = datetime(2018,3,22)  
for _ in range(5):    
    url = start_url.format(start.strftime("%Y%m%d"))  
    start -= timedelta(days=1)  
    page = requests.get(url)  
    tree = html.fromstring(page.content)  
    price = tree.xpath('//*[@id="quote-summary"]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/span/text()')  
    print(price)
```

**Output:**

```
['1,311.85']   
['1,311.85']  
['1,311.85']  
['1,311.85']  
['1,311.85']
```

Comment: Did you have a look at the requested url? If I'm not mistaken, you are missing the placeholder to be replaced with the date by `format`.

Comment: could you elaborate on that, I did check the URL, but it has no "date" substring as some URLs do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to load the website for different dates. Therefore you take the URL and try to append the date using `str.format`:

```
start_url = "https://in.finance.yahoo.com/quote/HINDUNILVR.NS?p=HINDUNILVR.NS"
start = datetime(2018,3,22)
url = start_url.format(start.strftime("%Y%m%d"))
```

The problem is that `format` doesn't know where to put the date, because you didn't define a placeholder. `url` looks like this after these three lines:

```
>>> start_url = "https://in.finance.yahoo.com/quote/HINDUNILVR.NS?p=HINDUNILVR.NS"
>>> start = datetime(2018,3,22)
>>> start_url.format(start.strftime("%Y%m%d"))
'https://in.finance.yahoo.com/quote/HINDUNILVR.NS?p=HINDUNILVR.NS'
```

To add the date to the URL, you have to specify a placeholder:

```
>>> start_url = "https://in.finance.yahoo.com/quote/HINDUNILVR.NS?p=HINDUNILVR.NS{0}"
```

Note the `{0}` at the end. This is where `format` will put the string generated by `start.strftime("%Y%m%d")`:

```
>>> start_url.format(start.strftime("%Y%m%d"))
'https://in.finance.yahoo.com/quote/HINDUNILVR.NS?p=HINDUNILVR.NS20180322'
```

It doesn't make sense to put it there, it's just to demonstrate how `format` works. You need to adapt your URL accordingly, by, e.g., adding a `?date=` parameter.

Comment: Thanks for that. How do you recommend I go about with the placeholder in this situation. How do I add a "?date=" parameter in this case, this site is not controlled by me right?  Sorry for my ignorance. I'm very new to this.

Comment: Well, if the site doesn't allow you to call it with a date parameter, there is no chance to use it.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification